# confusion with union and struct

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am working on a project in PCL (Point Cloud Library, www.pointclouds.org)
with this library I can get a 3D representation of what my Kinect is looking at.
the problem is, I am using this struct:

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
            unsigned char Blue;
            unsigned char Green;
            unsigned char Red;
            unsigned char Alpha;
    };
    float float_value;
    uint32_t long_value;
} RGBValue;
```

What I want to do with this struct, is to get the individual data from each color and put them in floats:

```
float R = someCloud->points[idx].rgba.Red;   
float G = someCloud->points[idx].rgba.Green;  
float B = someCloud->points[idx].rgba.Blue;  
float A = someCloud->points[idx].rgba.Alpha;
```

the error I am getting is this:

```
error C2039: 'Red' : is not a member of 'System::UInt32'*
```

Comment: Have you named your struct?

Comment: is `points` an array of `RGBValue` instances?

Comment: What is `rgba` in the expression `someCloud->points[idx].rgba.Red;   
`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must name your anonymous struct instance accordingly

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned char Blue;
        unsigned char Green;
        unsigned char Red;
        unsigned char Alpha;
    } rgba;

    float float_value;
    uint32_t long_value;
} RGBValue;
```

You can then access the members as

```
RGBValue v;
float R = v.rgba.Red;
float G = v.rgba.Green;
float B = v.rgba.Blue;
float A = v.rgba.Alpha;
```

Comment: Well, to be correct, this doesn't give the struct a name but the struct *instance*. And without the name there is no instance at all.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but your text is wrong. That's _not_ naming a struct, that's instancing an anonymous struct.

Comment: @leemes, JackAidley You're both correct, I've been sloppy in my answer. Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned char Blue;
        unsigned char Green;
        unsigned char Red;
        unsigned char Alpha;
    };
    float float_value;
    uint32_t long_value;
} RGBValue;
```

declares a union *type*, with a nested struct *type*.  The union only contains a `float` or a `uint32_t` - you never declared an *instance* of your nested struct.

You can give your type a name, so you can use it elsewhere:

```
typedef union
{
    struct RGBA // named struct type
    {
        unsigned char Blue;
        unsigned char Green;
        unsigned char Red;
        unsigned char Alpha;
    };
    RGBA rgba; // AND an instance of that type
    float float_value;
    uint32_t long_value;
} RGBValue;
```

or leave the type anonymous and just declare an instance, as Olaf showed. (The named type in my example can be referred to as `RGBValue::RGBA`)